# Why is django's development automatic static file server not suitable for production?

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

As stated in: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

When DEBUG is set to True, the server automatically serves the static file, but it states:

```
This method is grossly inefficient and probably insecure, so it is unsuitable for production.
```

But what exactly is inefficient and insecure about it? I just have a small-ish project on Heroku that I haven't set to "production" mode yet and I'm wondering what are the exact downsides.

Answer (score 7):

Performance related reasons:

- web servers are orders of magnitude better at serving static files.
- AFAIK the development server is mono-threaded and can respond only one request at time, concurrent requests will block (most browsers make 4 concurrent requests trying to download assets in parallel).

Security related reasons:

- using the app to serve static content is overkill (simplification is good for security)
- the developers like to be on the safe side, so it is kind of a disclaimer
- debug mode exposes a lot of information about the server

Django started in the news publishing industry where in general there is enough traffic to justify serving static content from a dedicated web server, probably the original developers have a bias for this arrangement.

That said, there are projects that replace the default development server by a more robust implementation based on gunicorn or tornado.

Answer (score 6):

Kenneth (the author of [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/), employed by Heroku) has a different opinion ([source](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/issues/32#issuecomment-7224498)):

> In reality, serving static files through Python/Django is fine for
>   production — those requests are no different than dynamic ones.
>
> Performance will be fantastic, but not as good as nginx.
>
> If you're that heavily concerned about efficiency then you shouldn't
>   be hosting those files on your server anyway, you'd be pushing them to
>   an CDN like S3+Cloudfront and the like.
>
> Another benefit to this approach is development:production parity.

And on heroku, you can't use Nginx to server static files, actually you can't do it on most other PaaS too, I got the same problem on cloud foundry last year. But there is a workaround:

> On Heroku, your application directly responds to HTTP requests,
>   instead of going through an additional web server like Apache or
>   Nginx.
>
> We recommend most applications serve their assets strait from Django
>   or a CDN.
>
> Django doesn't recommend serving static files in production because of
>   the design of its static file handler.
>
> Luckily, there is a library called DJ-Static which makes uses a
>   production-ready WSGI asset server.
>
> I've written up a guide for Django and Static Assets here:
>   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets

Read the following  discussions for more details:

[Serving static files for a Django app](https://discussion.heroku.com/t/serving-static-files-for-a-django-app/19/4)

[serving static files via gunicorn](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/issues/32)